# Admob banner не отображается

Tags: java, android, admob

Добавил в Activity баннер Admob, при указании id тестовой рекламы-заглушки баннер отображается, но когда вставляю id своего баннера из Admob, он не появляется и в `onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode)` выдает код ошибки 0 - `ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR`.

onCreate() aктивити

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, getString(R.string.admob_app_id));


mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice("цифры")
            .build();
```

xml

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_banner">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Приложение в Google Play не размещено. 
в чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: Вы разрешили приложению доступ в сеть? uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" в манифесте?

Comment: Если все разрешения есть то на тест девайсе может не отображаться, у меня так. Попробуйте убрать тест девайс для пробы, все должно работать.